# Не выходит проверка на введенные пользователем значения

Tags: c++

Код ошибок не вызывает, однако, при запуске кода - он даже не ждет пока пользователь введет значение и просто закрывается. Как это исправить? Так же интересует: обязательно ли (...) в catch блоке, или нужно словить какой-то определенный exception?

```
void d() {
    int f;
    try {
        std::cin>>f;
    } catch(...) {
        if(f!=1 | f!=2 | f!=3) {
            std::cin>>f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В следующий раз вставляйте код текстом, а не картинкой...

Comment: Замените изображение текстом, иначе ваш вопрос закроют.

Comment: Условие, если я правильно понимаю его смысл, должно выглядеть так:     if (f!=1 || f!=2 || f!=3)  Вот это: f1 || f2 - логический оператор, объединяющий две части условия, а вот это: f1 | f2 - побитовый оператор, выполняющий операцию ИЛИ попарно над битами переменных f1 и f2

Comment: При if (f!=1 || f!=2 || f!=3) - пишет code will never be executed.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/syvK9.png

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас какой-то мусор попадает в `cin` с прошлого ввода или вывода, используйте
`cin.ignore();` перед чтением строки.

Оператор `catch` сработает только в том случае, если будет выброшено исключение, скорее всего сам `cin` его не вызовет.

А для того чтобы он точно вызвался нужно его выбросить самостоятельно с помощью `throw`.

```
void d() {
    int f;
    try {
       std::cin.ignore() 
       std::cin>>f;
       if(f!=1 || f!=2 || f!=3){
          throw(f);
       }
    } catch(...) {
         std::cout<<"Exception is occurred";
    }
}
```

Comment: Qt Creator все равно гнет свою линию и пишет code will never be executed.

Comment: Правильно гнет.  У Вас условие выполняется ВСЕГДА.  Вот он и ругается,  что ветка else (отсутствующая)  никогда не выполнится

Comment: да, @ЮрийКозлов правильно говорит, может вы имели ввиду f!=1 && f!=2 && !=3

Answer (score 0):

1) Поставьте галку Run in terminal

[image: Run in terminal]

2) Как вам уже скаазли `if(f!=1 | f!=2 | f!=3)` выполянет побитовое or. А вам, скорее всего, нужно логическое - `||`

3) Но даже правильно записанное условие смысла не имеет `if(f!=1 || f!=2 || f!=3)`. Оно всегда дает `true` и , возможно, какой-то ваш код из-за этого не никогда не выполнится(ветка `else`?). О чем вас и предупреждает статический анализатор или компилятор. Возможно вам нужно логическое and - `&&`

4) iostream по-умолчанию не бросает исключения. Чтобы включить это поведение нужно иcпользовать [`std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions)

Comment: Почему условие всегда дает false???   Это же ИЛИ.  Если одно из этих условий ложно (f=1, например)  то два других гарантировано истины,  а значит и все условие истино, то есть всегда дает true

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, да, вы правы, это ошибка. Исправил